# Could not initialize class com.tridion.linking.Linking

Tags: tridion

I'm getting the error below for a .NET Tridion 2011 SP1 Web application we're developing. As far as I can tell following documentation, all required assemblies and jar files are installed in the bin directory, and all configured to point to a license file (recently generated).

Anyone know from previous experience what could be causing this?

## Could not initialize class com.tridion.linking.Linking

Some configured classpath roots cannot be found

================================================

ClassPath           : C:\Websites\Live\malvern.com.en\bin\bin
   ClassPath           : C:\Websites\Live\malvern.com.en\bin\bin
   ClassPath           : C:\Websites\Live\malvern.com.en\bin\bin

============================================================
Some Java classes or interfaces could not be found or loaded

The most typical reasons for this problem are:

- you forgot to configure a classpath
- a jarfile, zipfile, or directory is missing from your
  classpath
- you have a typo in one of your classpath entries
- a jarfile required by one of your classes is missing from
  your classpath
- a jarfile on your classpath is out-of-date and does not
  contain some new classes

============================================================

javax.servlet.jsp.tagext.TagSupport
 com.tridion.web.jsp.tag.DynamicComponentLinkHandler
 com.tridion.web.jsp.tag.IncrementKeyHandler
 javax.servlet.http.Cookie
 com.tridion.marketingsolution.profilesync.Handler
 com.tridion.smarttarget.tags.PromotionContentTagHandler
 com.tridion.smarttarget.tags.PromotionTagHandler
 com.tridion.webservices.odata.ODataPublicationMappingFilter
 com.tridion.web.jsp.tag.ConditionHandler
 com.tridion.web.jsp.ResponseWrapper
 com.tridion.smarttarget.tags.AttributeTagHandler
 com.tridion.smarttarget.tags.ItemContentTagHandler
 com.tridion.web.jsp.tag.ConditionsHandler
 javax.servlet.jsp.JspException
 [Ljavax.servlet.http.Cookie;
 com.tridion.linking.Linking
 com.tridion.smarttarget.tags.FallbackContentTagHandler
 com.tridion.web.jsp.tag.ComponentLinkHandler
 com.tridion.web.jsp.tag.ComponentPresentationHandler
 com.tridion.web.Admin
 com.tridion.webservices.odata.ODataContextListener
 com.tridion.web.jsp.JSPProcessor
 com.tridion.smarttarget.tags.QueryTagHandler
 com.tridion.web.asp.ASPAdmin
 com.tridion.web.jsp.tag.TargetGroupHandler
 com.tridion.linking.ASPLinking
 com.tridion.web.jsp.tag.BinaryLinkHandler
 javax.servlet.jsp.tagext.BodyTagSupport
 com.tridion.ambientdata.web.AmbientDataServletFilter
 com.tridion.smarttarget.tags.SearchTagHandler
 com.tridion.webservices.security.authentication.OAuth2AccessTokenHandler
 javax.servlet.jsp.JspTagException
 com.tridion.smarttarget.tags.FacetTagHandler
 com.tridion.smarttarget.tags.ItemContentInfoTagHandler
 com.tridion.web.jsp.JSPXSLTProcessor
 com.tridion.smarttarget.tags.ItemTagHandler
 com.tridion.web.jsp.tag.PageLinkHandler
 com.tridion.web.jsp.tag.TaxonomyHandler
 javax.servlet.jsp.tagext.Tag
 javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest
 javax.servlet.jsp.tagext.BodyTag
 javax.servlet.ServletRequest
 com.tridion.web.jsp.tag.LinkBaseHandler
 javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse
 javax.servlet.jsp.tagext.IterationTag
 javax.servlet.ServletResponse

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

## Exception Details: Java.Lang.Throwable: Could not initialize class com.tridion.linking.Linking

Some configured classpath roots cannot be found

================================================

ClassPath           : C:\Websites\Live\malvern.com.en\bin\bin
   ClassPath           : C:\Websites\Live\malvern.com.en\bin\bin
   ClassPath           : C:\Websites\Live\malvern.com.en\bin\bin

============================================================
Some Java classes or interfaces could not be found or loaded

The most typical reasons for this problem are:

- you forgot to configure a classpath
- a jarfile, zipfile, or directory is missing from your
  classpath
- you have a typo in one of your classpath entries
- a jarfile required by one of your classes is missing from
  your classpath
- a jarfile on your classpath is out-of-date and does not
  contain some new classes

============================================================

javax.servlet.jsp.tagext.TagSupport
 com.tridion.web.jsp.tag.DynamicComponentLinkHandler
 com.tridion.web.jsp.tag.IncrementKeyHandler
 javax.servlet.http.Cookie
 com.tridion.marketingsolution.profilesync.Handler
 com.tridion.smarttarget.tags.PromotionContentTagHandler
 com.tridion.smarttarget.tags.PromotionTagHandler
 com.tridion.webservices.odata.ODataPublicationMappingFilter
 com.tridion.web.jsp.tag.ConditionHandler
 com.tridion.web.jsp.ResponseWrapper
 com.tridion.smarttarget.tags.AttributeTagHandler
 com.tridion.smarttarget.tags.ItemContentTagHandler
 com.tridion.web.jsp.tag.ConditionsHandler
 javax.servlet.jsp.JspException
 [Ljavax.servlet.http.Cookie;
 com.tridion.linking.Linking
 com.tridion.smarttarget.tags.FallbackContentTagHandler
 com.tridion.web.jsp.tag.ComponentLinkHandler
 com.tridion.web.jsp.tag.ComponentPresentationHandler
 com.tridion.web.Admin
 com.tridion.webservices.odata.ODataContextListener
 com.tridion.web.jsp.JSPProcessor
 com.tridion.smarttarget.tags.QueryTagHandler
 com.tridion.web.asp.ASPAdmin
 com.tridion.web.jsp.tag.TargetGroupHandler
 com.tridion.linking.ASPLinking
 com.tridion.web.jsp.tag.BinaryLinkHandler
 javax.servlet.jsp.tagext.BodyTagSupport
 com.tridion.ambientdata.web.AmbientDataServletFilter
 com.tridion.smarttarget.tags.SearchTagHandler
 com.tridion.webservices.security.authentication.OAuth2AccessTokenHandler
 javax.servlet.jsp.JspTagException
 com.tridion.smarttarget.tags.FacetTagHandler
 com.tridion.smarttarget.tags.ItemContentInfoTagHandler
 com.tridion.web.jsp.JSPXSLTProcessor
 com.tridion.smarttarget.tags.ItemTagHandler
 com.tridion.web.jsp.tag.PageLinkHandler
 com.tridion.web.jsp.tag.TaxonomyHandler
 javax.servlet.jsp.tagext.Tag
 javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest
 javax.servlet.jsp.tagext.BodyTag
 javax.servlet.ServletRequest
 com.tridion.web.jsp.tag.LinkBaseHandler
 javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse
 javax.servlet.jsp.tagext.IterationTag
 javax.servlet.ServletResponse

Source Error:

Line 35: 
Line 36: <% Tridion.ContentDelivery.Web.Linking.ComponentLink componentLink = null; %>
Line 37: <% Tridion.ContentDelivery.Web.Linking.Link link = null; %>
Line 38: 
Line 39:

Source File: c:\Websites\Live\malvern.com.en\default.aspx    Line: 37

Stack Trace:

## [Throwable: Could not initialize class com.tridion.linking.Linking

Some configured classpath roots cannot be found

================================================

```
ClassPath           : C:\Websites\Live\malvern.com.en\bin\bin
ClassPath           : C:\Websites\Live\malvern.com.en\bin\bin
ClassPath           : C:\Websites\Live\malvern.com.en\bin\bin
```

============================================================
Some Java classes or interfaces could not be found or loaded

The most typical reasons for this problem are:

- you forgot to configure a classpath
- a jarfile, zipfile, or directory is missing from your
  classpath
- you have a typo in one of your classpath entries
- a jarfile required by one of your classes is missing from
  your classpath
- a jarfile on your classpath is out-of-date and does not
  contain some new classes

============================================================

javax.servlet.jsp.tagext.TagSupport
  com.tridion.web.jsp.tag.DynamicComponentLinkHandler
  com.tridion.web.jsp.tag.IncrementKeyHandler
  javax.servlet.http.Cookie
  com.tridion.marketingsolution.profilesync.Handler
  com.tridion.smarttarget.tags.PromotionContentTagHandler
  com.tridion.smarttarget.tags.PromotionTagHandler
  com.tridion.webservices.odata.ODataPublicationMappingFilter
  com.tridion.web.jsp.tag.ConditionHandler
  com.tridion.web.jsp.ResponseWrapper
  com.tridion.smarttarget.tags.AttributeTagHandler
  com.tridion.smarttarget.tags.ItemContentTagHandler
  com.tridion.web.jsp.tag.ConditionsHandler
  javax.servlet.jsp.JspException
  [Ljavax.servlet.http.Cookie;
  com.tridion.linking.Linking
  com.tridion.smarttarget.tags.FallbackContentTagHandler
  com.tridion.web.jsp.tag.ComponentLinkHandler
  com.tridion.web.jsp.tag.ComponentPresentationHandler
  com.tridion.web.Admin
  com.tridion.webservices.odata.ODataContextListener
  com.tridion.web.jsp.JSPProcessor
  com.tridion.smarttarget.tags.QueryTagHandler
  com.tridion.web.asp.ASPAdmin
  com.tridion.web.jsp.tag.TargetGroupHandler
  com.tridion.linking.ASPLinking
  com.tridion.web.jsp.tag.BinaryLinkHandler
  javax.servlet.jsp.tagext.BodyTagSupport
  com.tridion.ambientdata.web.AmbientDataServletFilter
  com.tridion.smarttarget.tags.SearchTagHandler
  com.tridion.webservices.security.authentication.OAuth2AccessTokenHandler
  javax.servlet.jsp.JspTagException
  com.tridion.smarttarget.tags.FacetTagHandler
  com.tridion.smarttarget.tags.ItemContentInfoTagHandler
  com.tridion.web.jsp.JSPXSLTProcessor
  com.tridion.smarttarget.tags.ItemTagHandler
  com.tridion.web.jsp.tag.PageLinkHandler
  com.tridion.web.jsp.tag.TaxonomyHandler
  javax.servlet.jsp.tagext.Tag
  javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest
  javax.servlet.jsp.tagext.BodyTag
  javax.servlet.ServletRequest
  com.tridion.web.jsp.tag.LinkBaseHandler
  javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse
  javax.servlet.jsp.tagext.IterationTag
  javax.servlet.ServletResponse

]
   Codemesh.JuggerNET.NTypeValue.Throw(Int64 inst) +514
   Codemesh.JuggerNET.JavaClass.ThrowTypedException(Int64 inst) +1243
   Codemesh.JuggerNET.JavaMethod.CallObject(JavaProxy jpo, JavaMethodArguments args) +915
   Com.Tridion.Linking.ComponentLink..ctor(Int32 publicationId) +154
   Tridion.ContentDelivery.Web.UI.ComponentLink.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer) +193
   ASP.default_aspx.__RenderbodyContent(HtmlTextWriter __w, Control parameterContainer) in c:\Websites\Live\malvern.com.en\default.aspx:37
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children) +131
   ASP.includes_site_master.__RenderForm1(HtmlTextWriter __w, Control parameterContainer) in c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\8694a1d7\ddf129e2\App_Web_0p0okahq.0.cs:0
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children) +131
   System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlForm.RenderChildren(HtmlTextWriter writer) +315
   System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlContainerControl.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer) +48
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children) +246
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children) +246
   System.Web.UI.Page.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer) +40
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +5290

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you might have some missing config, or some misconfiguration somewhere. Part 1 of Peter's answer to [Presentation Error - SmartTarget Page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11047381/presentation-error-smarttarget-page) provides a link to some information that could be useful.

Comment: Agree. Don't be mislead by the strange 'bin\bin' path. It usually means that you are missing some jars. Check if you have a bin\lib with the correct Tridion jars, or if not, if you have a %TRIDION_HOME%\lib.

Comment: I also find the docs to be a thorough reference for manually setting up content delivery - following them step-by-step has meant that it has always worked first time for me :)

Comment: thanks guys :) I'll have a read through and see if it brings me some joy

Comment: ok I've attempted to follow the universal procedure for installing a website on a presentation server, still no luck :( - I've got the site working when both CD and CM sit on the same server, but now the site itself is being hosted on a different server am I starting to encounter this issue. Copying the bin directory (including assemblies, config and lib folders) from the working website doesn't work

Comment: It seems like you may not have the valid license file. Check your license file location is correct in all config and the license file exists as well. Also, Is your license file valid for the machine name (server) you're running the CDA ?

Comment: That's an excellent point - checked the cd_licenses file and discovered they were NOT for the server I was working on, corrected it now and replaced the licence file with a new one but same issue

Comment: Sorry getting ahead of myself, cleared down Temporary Internet Files and everything works fine now - invalid licence was the issue. Thanks for your help everyone!

Comment: I had this error message after publishing a missing (nested) .NET Master Page.  Restarting the website (by making a minor change to the web.config) sorted the problem.